# Trying to check value of process.communicate()

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I'm having some problems reading the value of a returned command from within a python script.  The idea here is light a LED when a song is playing, and turn the LED off when the song is stopped or paused.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

ledpin = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(ledpin, GPIO.OUT)

try:
 while True:
   process = subprocess.Popen("mpc status|grep -o playing", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   output = process.communicate()[0]

   if output == "playing" : #if output is playing
    print "Song Playing"
    GPIO.output(ledpin,GPIO.HIGH)

   else : #output is anything else 
    print "Waiting for music"
    GPIO.output(ledpin,GPIO.LOW)

   time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

It's printing the variable output, which shows up as "playing" exactly as expected, but it's never caught in the if loop - I only ever see "Waiting for music".  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You could have a [look at this code](https://github.com/garyconstable/python-media-player/blob/master/mpc.py) and see how it's done (untested by me). Do a `print(output)` to see what you're actually getting - you are **not** printing this, as you say.

Comment: Changing `print output` to `print(output)` returns the same thing either way.

Comment: Neither is in the code you posted, so only you know what your code *actually* looks like...

Comment: any whitespace like "   playing" or "playing   " ? You can try to change: if output == "playing" to if "playing" in output.

Comment: How about `if "playing" in output.tolower():`?

Comment: `if "playing" in output` did it.  Thank you all.

Comment: my bad @handle, I just realized i pasted the code before I added the debugging print statement to show what output contained.  I added it in both sections of the if/else.